# Websphere - What is the best way to hide wsdl's from end user?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere

I think there are several ways to hide wsdl's from end users for WebSphere (6.1). We use axis to publish Web Services and I currently updated the custom Servlet class (which extends AxisServlet) and override the service method to throw 404 error for urls like: http://xxxx/services/MyService?wsdl. The other option may be adding filters.

Are there any other alternative ways?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you expect users of `MyService` to guess?

Comment: @lutz The reason is simple: security and I think this is a general question independent from the name of the service. Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_by_obscurity

Answer (score 1):

What lutz pointed to is correct. You should add some authentication mechanism to your SOAP interfaces if they can do something potentially harmful. However if you insist you can block the access to anything that looks like wsdl query, for instance with

- [Servlet Filter](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) for your applications
- Front-end web server configuration that will redirect those queries to somewhere else, ie.

> ```
> RewriteEngine On
> RewriteRule ^(.+)?wsdl$ /error.html
> ```